# Connecting the components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to develop a website in Angular. My website happens to be a Multi-Page Application (MPA), where different pages have been developed as different components. I have developed those pages of the website, I was just wondering how can connect those components/pages together like on a button click, the user should be directed to another page, etc.

Also, it would be really great if anyone could provide any references to some resources or tutorials where they teach us how to develop Multi-Page Application (MPA) with the help of Angular. I searched online for quite a while and didn't find anything since Angular is mostly used for Single Page Applications (SPA).

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: Angular. (Made the edit in the question)

Comment: I've removed the AngularJS tag

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario it is really important to have some kind of state saving as a SPA does lose its state on hard reload i.e. CTRL+R.

A common approach would be the **use of the `localStorage`** to preserve your data that you need to restore the state, but the downside of it is the security as it can be viewed from the devtools.

Another approach would be the **use of cookies** which requires a backend. I think this is straight forward and commonly asked how to implement cookies.

That's the same approaches how other SSR (server side redered) pages are handle its state.

**Additionally:**

I think I kinda guessed your problem as you just have different component on different routes. Angular is a SPA, but this does not mean it cannot change the route. It will change the route, but without reloading the browser. There you can reach other components. More about that I would recomment to read this `Tour of Heroes` example:

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: cookies don't require a backend

Comment: It is required to restore the state of course, but you are right, not for the cookie creation.